# What's the benefit of using Nginx to serve a Flask API on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, nginx, amazon-ecs, flask

I want to deploy a Flask API on AWS using Docker. A common way seems to be using a combination of Nginx + app server (e.g Gunicorn) + Flask app.

The reason to use app server seems obvious to me. However, since I plan to use AWS ALB I'm not sure if there's a need for Nginx anymore? From my understanding Nginx is used for connection handling and serving static resources. In my case I don't need any of these: the connection is handled already by ALB (AFAIK) and I won't have to serve static resources.

Are there any other advantages of using Nginx for a low latency API service?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are using the [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), you'll still need some way of "serving" your Flask API.  You will also need to provision an EC2 instance and run something to serve your API.  Instead of running a windows EC2 instance with IIS you can save about 50% operating cost and use Nginx on a linux EC2 instance.  Additionally, Nginx can be used as a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), and supports [caching](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/) which you may find beneficial.

However, because you are using an Application Load Balancer and are looking into Gunicorn to serve the API you probably don't *need* Nginx, and it would just require more overhead for deployments if you are not going to setup any of the features in Nginx.

Comment: Should have mentioned earlier, I will be using ECS + Fargate to run the container. The reverse proxy capability is already handled by ALB. Caching, however, might be a good point.